# blank screen when pressing backbutton in webview

Tags: android, webview

Here in below activity i am displaying a webpage. When i press backbutton i want to go MainActivity.class but it displays blank screen and after that if i press the backbutton again then it shows me the MainActivity.However now i solved it myself. what i did was i write finish(); just after wv.loadUrl(url). It's working fine now. Can anyone please explain why it was not working before.

```
public class LinkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView wv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_link);
        wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        wv.loadUrl(url);
        wv.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        finish();
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(LinkActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok now i understand your problem

Blank screen is just your LinkActivity with no webpage load since your loadurl function call web browser

```
wv.loadUrl(url);
```

if you don't implement your own client and override url
is calling web browser outside of your activity

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

use this with

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

so that url request load in your application rather than browser

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I am a newbie. Just one more question..is it necessary to use WebViewClient?...is there anything wrong if i call finish after loading webpage?

Comment: there is nothing wrong it will just destroy your activity if you want implement some more logic in webview WebViewClient is necessary

Answer (score 0):

The `finish()` should come after `startActivity`. Try this:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(LinkActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent1);
finish();
```

Comment: i think it doesn't matter where you put finish. However i tried that it didn't worked.

Comment: I wrote finish(); after calling wv.loadUrl(url). It's working fine now. However not sure how it is working..lol

Answer (score 0):

i think you should override this function instead setOnKeyListener since onkeylistener triggered twice down & up it might do unwanted behaviour

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(LinkActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent1);    
}
```

or you can do filter on onkeylistener

```
 wv.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {                           
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            //This is the filter
            if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                return true;

            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK: 
                    finish();
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(LinkActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but its not working. Just to let you that MainActivity is a listview.

Comment: I wrote finish(); after calling wv.loadUrl(url). It's working fine now. However not sure how it is working..lol

Comment: check my new answer